# NullReferenceException when calling NavigationContext

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

In a Click function I use

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?day=" + this.week.SelectedIndex, UriKind.Relative));
```

to navigate to MainPage.xaml with a value which indicate the Panorama.DefaultItem,and in MainPage.xaml.cs I write like

```
if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("day"))
{
    schedule.DefaultItem = NavigationContext.QueryString["day"];
}
```

but a NullReferenceException comes out in

```
this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("day")
```

and I don't know where the wrong is,I will be appreciate if somebody can help me with this problem...

Comment: Do you have any debugging capabilities? If so, print out what the QueryString contains, to check that you're getting what you think you should be getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Is NavigationContext or QueryString null?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I bet you are accessing `NavigationContext` in the constructor. The framework hasn't filled that in yet at that point. Check it in `OnNavigatedTo` or any time after and you should be fine.